# Grunt minall task ends with 'Killed'

Tags: angularjs, gruntjs

I'm trying to get a copy of my Angular app over to a VPS of mine. I have it working on a VM right now, but am pulling the source files and building angular.

I had the error previously so I did a bunch of Googling and tried with a new image of my VPS, but to no avail.

Here's my `grunt package` output:

```
Running "bower" task

Running "clean:build" (clean) task
Cleaning build...OK

Running "clean:tmp" (clean) task
Cleaning tmp...OK

Running "buildall" task
>> File build/angular-scenario.js created.
>> File build/angular.js created.
>> File build/angular-loader.js created.
>> File build/angular-touch.js created.
>> File build/angular-mocks.js created.
>> File build/angular-sanitize.js created.
>> File build/angular-resource.js created.
>> File build/angular-animate.js created.
>> File build/angular-route.js created.
>> File build/angular-cookies.js created.
>> File tmp/promises-aplus-adapter++.js created.

Running "minall" task
Killed
```

Notice nothing shows up under `Running "minall" task`, only "Killed". On my VM it had output so I'm assuming this is the problem. Any ideas?

This is on Ubuntu 13.10 x64 server.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll bet you're running out of memory during the build.

Comment: That's probably it actually, the VPS is only 512mb of RAM...any way around it?

Comment: Not that I know of, other than maybe not using the minified version?

Comment: Shouldn't swap space address running out of physical memory?

Comment: Only if you actually use swap space _and have enough of it_. Digital Ocean droplets don't come with swap by default, in any case.